# how to us the case_when function for a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, case

I have do a list of dataframe want to change the values according to case_when function. I don't know how to apply on a list.

```
mutate(FLOOR = case_when("FLOOR" == 1 ~ "1",
                                 TRUE ~ "0"),
               LIGHTING = case_when(LIGHTING == 1 ~ "1", 
                                    TRUE ~ "0"),
               COOKING = case_when(COOKING == 1 ~ "1",
                                   TRUE ~ "0"),
               DRINKING_W = case_when(DRINKING_W == 1 ~ "1", 
                                      TRUE ~ "0"),
               TOILET = case_when(TOILET == 1 ~ "1",
                                  TRUE ~ "0")
```

This is one dataframe reproducible example. I can apply on a single dataframe but neet to apply on a list.

```
df1 <- dput(head(aceh[[2]]))
structure(list(FLOOR = c(1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), LIGHTING = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 4, 1), COOKING = c(3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3), DRINKING_W = c(1, 
2, 2, 5, 7, 8), TOILET = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4), SEPTIC_TAN = c(1, 
2, 2, 3, 1, 0), TELEPHONE = c(2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2), TENURE = c(1, 
1, 1, 4, 1, 1)), row.names = c(7L, 9L, 10L, 65L, 66L, 10578L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(FLOOR = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 3), LIGHTING = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1), COOKING = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), DRINKING_W = c(7, 
7, 7, 7, 8, 8), TOILET = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), SEPTIC_TAN = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 0, 0), TELEPHONE = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2), TENURE = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2)), row.names = 252098:252103, class = "data.frame")

sample <- as.list(df1, df2)
```

Thank you for your helping.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Generally, check the purrr package or lapply function on how to do things in lists.

Comment: @deschen Could you write it?

Comment: The data you provided is, well technically a list (since data frames are lists), but it is a a data frame, hence your code shoudl just work fine on the provided example data.

Comment: need to make function to apply on the list.  which I cannot do.

Comment: Then please provide an example of the full list (I suppose `aceh`), not just an example of one data frame from that list.

Comment: I have added and you can work on sample. Thanks!

Comment: does the solution solve your problem? If so, please consider accepting is as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your example still doesn't work, i.e. I assume you want `list (df1, df2)`, not `as.list(df1, df2)`, but here's a simple solution. Basically just use map (or lapply if you want a base R solution) which goes through each list element and applies the function specified in `.f`. And in your case the fcuntion is simply to do some recoding:

```
library(tidyverse)
list(df1, df2) |> 
  map(.f = ~ .x |> mutate(FLOOR = case_when("FLOOR" == 1 ~ "1",
                                            TRUE ~ "0"),
                          LIGHTING = case_when(LIGHTING == 1 ~ "1", 
                                               TRUE ~ "0"),
                          COOKING = case_when(COOKING == 1 ~ "1",
                                              TRUE ~ "0"),
                          DRINKING_W = case_when(DRINKING_W == 1 ~ "1", 
                                                 TRUE ~ "0"),
                          TOILET = case_when(TOILET == 1 ~ "1",
                                             TRUE ~ "0")))

[[1]]
      FLOOR LIGHTING COOKING DRINKING_W TOILET SEPTIC_TAN TELEPHONE TENURE
7         0        1       0          1      1          1         2      1
9         0        1       0          0      1          2         4      1
10        0        1       0          0      1          2         4      1
65        0        1       0          0      1          3         4      4
66        0        0       0          0      1          1         4      1
10578     0        1       0          0      0          0         2      1

[[2]]
       FLOOR LIGHTING COOKING DRINKING_W TOILET SEPTIC_TAN TELEPHONE TENURE
252098     0        1       0          0      0          3         2      1
252099     0        1       0          0      0          3         2      1
252100     0        1       0          0      0          3         2      1
252101     0        1       0          0      0          3         2      1
252102     0        0       0          0      0          0         4      2
252103     0        1       0          0      0          0         2      2
```